# Can you run SQL Server Developer edition on a live production Windows server?

Tags: sql-server

The question comes as the Express version has a cap of 10 gb which my database is over. If the SQL Server Developer edition only allows certain amount of connections, would have a Windows server on another machine allow this to count as only 1 connection. If anyone has experience with a similar setup and can tell me about the experience. Looking to understand the cost of $4000 for SQL Server Standard version to the Developer version which seems to be have more features.

Comment: This question is not about programming.

Comment: Remember you are free to use multiple 10GB databases, and, since SQL Sever 2016 SP1 to use the advanced data compression features in Express Edition.

Comment: Off-topic because licenses questions should be directed to product vendor and this is not about programming.

Answer (score 6):

Literally answering your question, you *can* run SQL Server Developer Edition on a production server, however you *should not*. You will be in violation of Microsoft's Licensing terms:

> **SQL Server Developer Edition**
>
> SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition is a
> fully featured version of SQL Server software—including all the
> features and capabilities of Enterprise Edition—licensed for
> development, test and demonstration purposes only. SQL Server
> Developer Edition may not be used in a production environment or with
> commercial data. Any test data that was used for design, development
> or test purposes must be removed prior to deploying the software for
> production use.

Get the whole story [At Microsoft's SQL Server Website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing)